# passing variable containing special chars to sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I need to remove subdomains from file:

```
.domain.com
.sub.domain.com -- this must be removed
.domain.com.uk
.sub2.domain.com.uk -- this must be removed
```

so i have used sed :

```
sed '/\.domain.com$/d' file
sed '/\.domain.com.uk$/d' file
```

and this part was simple, but when i try to do it in the loop problems appears:

```
while read line
do
sed '/\$line$/d' filename > filename   
done < filename
```

I suppose it is "." and $ problem , have tried escaping it in many ways but i am out of ideas now.

Comment: your while loop is quite broken, you have `filename``in three different places... `sed` operates on each line of a file per default and can even do inline changes when using the `-i` flag.

Comment: The problem is that you are truncating the file being passed to `sed`.  Either use the `-i` option for `sed`, or redirect output to a temp file & move the temp file back/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution inspired by NeronLeVelu's idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x

domains=($(rev domains | sort))

for i in `seq 0 ${#domains[@]}` ;do
    domain=${domains[$i]}
    [ -z "$domain" ] && continue
    for j in `seq $i ${#domains[@]}` ;do
        [[ ${domains[$j]} =~ $domain.+  ]] && domains[$j]=
    done
done


for i in `seq 0 ${#domains[@]}` ;do
    [ -n "${domains[$i]}" ] && echo ${domains[$i]} | rev >> result.txt
done
```

For `cat domains`:

```
.domain.com
.sub.domain.com
.domain.co.uk
.sub2.domain.co.uk
sub.domain.co.uk
abc.yahoo.com
post.yahoo.com
yahoo.com
```

You get `cat result.txt`:

```
.domain.co.uk
.domain.com
yahoo.com
```

Comment: what [ -z "$domain" ] do with the string ?

Comment: that just checks if `$domain` is empty. It is necessary because I'm only setting the array field to an empty string, not removing it, so I have to skip it. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: @Kriss by the way, please always try to accept some answer to keep it a bit organized. It would also be great if you could work on the formulation of your question more because it might be very well useful to others but it is quite confusing as it stands now.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*/²&³/;H
$ {x;s/$/\
/
: again
  s|\(\n\)²\([^³]*\)³\(.*\)\1²[^³]*\2³|\1\2\3|
  t again
  s/[²³]//g;s/.\(.*\)./\1/
  p
  }' YourFile
```

Load the file in working buffer then remove (iterative) any line  that end with an earlier one, finally priont the result. Use of temporary edge delimiter easier to manage than \n in pattern

`--posix -e` for GNU sed (tested from AIX)

Comment: Check your formatting; I'm not sure what characters the superscript 2 and 3 are supposed to represent.

Comment: they are just char not often used (until recently) in domain name so they are perfect delimiter but nearly any char could be used. With new rules on domain name, other delimiter is maybe necessary (or at least check before that there are not part of the content)

Comment: Ah, OK, you intentionally add them, then remove them later.

Comment: I did not verify, but +1 for the idea :)

Comment: @chepner  right,often use this due to AIX sed limitation on control char between []

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is a bit confusing because you're trying to use `sed` to delete patterns from a file but you take the patterns from the same file.

If you really want to remove subdomains from `filename` then I suppose you need more something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x 

cp domains domains.tmp

while read domain
do
  sed -r -e "/[[:alnum:]]+${domain//./\\.}$/d" domains.tmp > domains.tmp2
  cp domains.tmp2 domains.tmp
done < dom.txt
```

Where `cat domains` is:

```
.domain.com
.sub.domain.com
.domain.co.uk
.sub2.domain.co.uk
sub.domain.co.uk
abc.yahoo.com
post.yahoo.com
```

and `cat dom.txt` is:

```
.domain.com
.domain.co.uk
.yahoo.com
```

Running the script on these inputs results in:

```
$ cat domains.tmp
.domain.com
.domain.co.uk
```

Each iteration will remove subdomains of `domain` currently read from `dom.txt`, store it in a temporary file the contents of which is used in the next iteration for additional filtering.

It's good to try your scripts with `set -x`, you'll see some of the substitutions, etc.

Comment: that's also wrong, you'll just overwrite the file in the first iteration

Comment: so i shoud to use vairable to load content into it maybe ?

Comment: in my opinion you should first and foremost  explain much better what you are trying to achieve :) Where do you get the patterns to delete from? From the file? From which file are you trying to delete? From the same file? Sounds weird. Is it an input parameter? Is the input parameter a regex? Or is the input parameter just a domain and you want to automatically delete all its subdomains?

Comment: this is a text file i shoved above. i need to remove all subdomains of domains in this file. And actually i did it using sed manually write each domain to check using: sed '/\.domain.com$/d' file - now i want to do it in the loop

Comment: in that case, why isn't my answer the solution? :) I'm trying to understand but I don't. To me it seems you don't need any loop if you just need to exclude subdomains. Especially if you have a short fixed list of what is a top-level domain (e.g. only .com and .co.uk). If the list is longer you might need a more complex solution.

Comment: is it working for abc.priv.pl , ghj.pl and tousands of others ?

Comment: What i want is to: get first line and use it as parameter in sed than write results someware. than get second line of results and use it as parameter for sed

Comment: Of course not, but that's exactly what is not specified in your question! If you want it to work for http://publicsuffix.org/ then say so!

Comment: @Kriss Have a look now. It's closer to what you want but it may still not be exactly it (for example you might need more than just the `:alnum:` character class, etc.).

Comment: But when i have got domain.co.uk and sub.domain.co.uk i need to remove sub.domain.co.uk and leave domain.co.uk - do you know what i mean. It is not about ends but whole domains like yahoo.com and post.yahoo.com abc.yahoo.com - i need to remove post.yahoo.com and abc.yahoo.com. But i probably know how to do it - when i do it i will post the script

Comment: I think I know what you mean but I think it's almost covered by my script. You just put domain.co.uk, yahoo.com to dom.txt and you remove one [[:alnum:]] from the regex and it will work.

Comment: almost but - i dont know what domains i want to remove - so i dont know what to put to dom.txt .I have to find the shortest domain on the list and use it as base - than i need to remove all subdomains of it

Comment: aha, then, I guess, you need a preprocessing step in which you will compute dom.txt exactly as you said. At least that would be a clean way of doing that, in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, it may be easier to do what NeronLeVelu suggests.