# Edit a few lines of uncompressed PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf, editline

I want to edit a few lines in an uncompressed pdf.
I found a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250177/en-masse-inline-editing-in-an-uncompressed-pdf) but since I need to scan the file a few times to get the exact line positions I want to change this doesn't really suit (and the pure number of RegEx matches are more than desired).
The pdf contains utf-8 encodable lines (a few of them I want to edit, bookmark target ids in particular)
and a lot of blobs (guess images and so on).
When I edit the file with notepad it's working fine, but when I do it programatically (reading in, changing a few lines, writing back)
images and some formatting is missing. (Sine they are not read in at the firstplace, ignore-option)

```
with codecs.open("merged-uncompressed.pdf", "r", encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as f:
```

I can read the file in with `errors="surrogateescape"` and wanted to map the lines from above import but don't know if this approach can work.

Does anyone know a way how to deal with this?

Best, Lukas

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this:

1. read the file as binary
2. marked the lines which couldn't be encoded utf-8
3. copied the list line by line to a temporary list ( not encodable lines were copied with a placholder 'None\n')
4. Then I went back to do the searching part on the copied list so I got my lines I wanted to replace
5. replaced the lines in the original binary list (same indices!)
6. wrote it back to file
7. the resulting pdf was a bit corupted because of whitespace before the target ids of the bookmarks but by recompressing qpdf fixed it:)

The code is very messy at the moment and so I don't want to publish it right now.
But I want to add it at github within the next few weeks.
If anyone needs it: just comment and it will have more priority.

Thanks to anyone who wanted to help:)
Lukas